# StackExchange accounts interface in jobs is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

When [editing my CV on jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit/), the interface to add or remove accounts is inconsistent with the rest of the ui on that page. To edit the accounts that are displayed, I have to click "edit" on an existing account, which is counter-intuitive. For other parts of the UI "edit and remove" edits or removes that thing, and an additional button is displayed to add things to that part of my CV.

As a result, it had me confused for a bit how I was supposed to add an account there.

[image: Part of the UI that is confusing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that we'll be fixing this because of on-going work to release Developer Story. That has a different interface for managing associated accounts and the old CV interface will be going away.